# Loop/Assign for MaxValue, MinValue and Calculate Interval

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I loop all my sheets, starting from the 2nd sheet.

I'm trying to:
In each sheet, find the max and minimum value on column F (it has header), calculate (maxvalue‑minvalue)/4 assigning the result to a variable (interval) and assign maxvalue, minvalue and interval to 3 cells in each sheet.

In the end, in all sheets starting from the second, J2 = Interval, K2 = MaxValue (of column F) and L2 = MinValue (of column F).

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, Interval As Object, MaxValue As Object, MinValue As Object

For x = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(x).Activate
    
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("F2:F" & Rows.Count)
    MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(c)
    MinValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(c)
    Interval = (MaxValue - MinValue) / 4
    Sheets("x").Range("J2").Value = Interval
    Sheets("x").Range("K1").Value = MaxValue
    Sheets("x").Range("L1").Value = MinValue
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

I get

> Run Time Error 91, Object or With not defined

Comment: changed your `MaxValue`, `MinValue` and `Interval` from `Object` to a number variable `(Integer,Long,Single,Double)`. Most people use `Long` but if your expecting decimals I would use `Double`

Comment: Hi Simon, good morning! Thanks so much for your help, buddy. I changed to Double and now I'm getting vba runtime error 9 subscript out of range. The error happens when the code try to run from "Interval = ..." to "Sheets("x").Range("J2").Value = ..."

Comment: I put an answer below. It's the quotes around the `x` for when your putting the variables into the sheet that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we are.

So first it's changing the variables from `Object` to `Double`. Your other issue was returning the values you used quotes over the `x`. By using quotes your making VBA think x is the sheet name rather than the number.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim x As Long, Interval As Double, MaxValue As Double, MinValue As Double

For x = 2 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(x).Activate
    
    Dim c As Range
    Set c = Range("F2:F" & Rows.Count)
        MaxValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(c)
        MinValue = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(c)
        Interval = (MaxValue - MinValue) / 4
        Sheets(x).Range("J2").Value = Interval
        Sheets(x).Range("K1").Value = MaxValue
        Sheets(x).Range("L1").Value = MinValue
        
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Hey Simon! Thanks soooooo much! It helped me a looot! You're great, buddy =D